# textBox value and button click count- executing code depedant on textbox value

Tags: c#, winforms

I am currently working with clicking count and textBox values. `Button1` purpose is to execute an specific function depending on the value that `texbox7` has. I am not getting any results when I try firing the button click event. Can someone suggest/help ?

**Code**

```
    private List<string> messages = new List<string>() { "Option1", "Option2", "Option3", "Option4" };
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

    if (textBox7.ToString() == "Option1")
                {
                    int min = max;
                    int n = 0;
                    string s = "";

                    sw.Start();


                }
                else if (textBox7.ToString() == "Option2")
                {
                }
                else if (textBox7.ToString() == "Option3")
                {
                }
                else if (textBox7.ToString() == "Option4")
                {
                }
                else if (textBox7.ToString() == "")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please input information");
                }
       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
if (textBox7.ToString() == "Option1")
```

it should be

```
if (textBox7.Text == "Option1")
```

You should compare with the value inside the TextBox, and you can get that using [Text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.text.aspx) property of the textbox.

Your `textBox7.ToString()` will give you something like `System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: text`. Because of that you are not getting into any check. Compare your values against the `Text` property and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [`TextBox.Text`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.text.aspx) property in a [`switch-case`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx) statement:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch (textBox7.Text)
    {
        case "Option1":
            //do something
        case "Option2":
            //do something
        case "Option3":
            //do some thing
        case "Option4":
            //do something
            break;
        // If the value of switch-Expression is not 1, 2, 3 or 4 the 
        // default case is executed.
        default:
            MessageBox.Show("Please input information");
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's Simple Use .Text property to get text value of textBox in code behind file
`textBox7.Text` property instead of 
`testBox7.ToString()` further mode use either `if-else` statements or `switch` statement as these both are conditional statements and execution based on condition.

cheer up!